# Simple LED Circuit on audio jack not working

Tags: led, audio, plug

I am trying to connect a simple LED to the audio jack of my phone.
Finally i got the correct voltage with the right audio plug (headset 4pols), which is arround 2.7V on my phone. But the LED is not lighting up?
Does anyone have an explanation for that. It's an red LED which should normaly light up with 2.7V

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhti8A.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: What is the output impedance of the headphone jack?

Comment: arround 0.7V. the LED is working.

Comment: "*Finally i got the correct voltage ... which is arround 2.7V on my phone.*" What does this mean? 2.7 V DC or AC audio? How exactly did you measure this? Are you expecting the LED to light when music is playing or all the time?

Comment: I measured with it with a multimeter. _2.7 V DC or AC audio?_ Honestly that ones other question. DC is 2.7V and AC 5V ? I hope the LED is lighting up at all. But finaly goal when music is playing.

Comment: Try measuring the voltage across the LED when it is connected to the phone. Other users, please see the previous question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/323744/voltage-of-smartphone-audio-jack

Comment: A red LED normally illuminates at about 2 volts and somewhere above 2.2 volts never works again due to current overload. I don't think you know what you are doing.

Comment: I am new to electronics... So how should i learn else? _A red LED normally illuminates at about 2 volts and somewhere above 2.2 volts never works again due to current overload._ Means i need higher voltage?

Comment: Start with some simple circuits that don't involve the headphone jack on your smartphone. Impedance isn't measured in volts. When someone says that the LED does **not** work again above 2.2V, that means you should **definitely** not apply more voltage. I'd suggest learning what Ohm's law is first.

Answer (score 2):

It is most likely because the mic bias circuit does not supply enough current to turn on your LED>

Below is what a typical PC sound card input looks like. Your phone's mic input is very similar, but is biased at 2.7V (which is a typical voltage to run a cell phone's analog circuits) and the bias resistor and audio ride on the same wire instead of 2 shown for the PC. The circuit is from here: http://www.hobby-hour.com/electronics/computer_microphone.php

[image: Typical Mic Input]

The 2.2k resistor provides a bias voltage required by the amplifier inside the condenser mic in your headset. On some phones, this resistor can be as high as 10k Ohms.

A red LED has a forward voltage of 1.8 Volts typically. Your supply is at 2.7V. So it looks like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmj0QAm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So let's do the math. In the best case, the internal bias resistor is 2.2k. Red LEDs typically have forward voltage drop of 1.8 Volts, so your LED current is (2.7 Volts - 1.8 Volts) / 2.2k Ohms = 0.182 mA. Pretty small. Repeat the calculation for 10k and you get 40 uA (0.040 mA). Miniscule!

Here's how you find out the value of the internal bias resistor without opening up your phone: set your multi-meter to the 20 mA range and then connect it between the mic and GND connection. Then use Ohms law to calculate R. So if you measure 1 mA, you would calculate: R = V / I = 2.7V / .001 = 2.7k Ohms.